# Visual Studio Code Terminal keeps showing "The system cannot find the path specified" on running Java

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I have tried everything available from google searches. But didn't help.
I have set JAVA.HOME, Environment Variable Path of Windows10 etc. everything. But still this thing is not solved. [image: How can I solve this?]

Answer (score 0):

1. Run `java --version` in Command Prompt to check If JDK was installed and added to the Path successfully.
2. Open Command Platte in VS Code (**Ctrl+Shift+P**) and Select **Java: Configure Java Runtime**:

[image]

**Java Tooling Runtime -> JDK for Language Server**: this one is `java.home` in User Settings.json, which needs JDK11 or recent version.

The JDK you've installed successfully will be shown in this list, then you can select the one you need.

Then **reload the window** to make the change work.

Comment: I have done those thing already. Even Java Tooling Runtime is showing accurately. 
i have change java.home json settings code and set path to the jdk. still is not working :(

Comment: @Shahriar Mim. the configuration would work only after reloading the window. Have your question been solved?

Comment: I tried that time. then I didn't try the VS Code again. I even restart my pc several times.

Comment: @ShahriarMim, Is there any possibility that the jdk you installed was broken? Try to download and install **AdoptOpenJDK** from [official website](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-tutorial#_installing-a-java-development-kit-jdk). see if the question goes away.